# Find Index Of the Same Element in Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, sorting

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Apple"];
 console.log(fruits.indexOf("Apple") );
```

Is there a way to find the index of the same element in an array, for example, "Apple" is at the index of 2 and 4 and the output should be in an array [2,4] ? Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/index-of-all - A concise and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reduce` the array to array of indexes, which value is **Apple**:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Apple"];

const indexes = fruits.reduce((r, n, i) => {
  n === "Apple" && r.push(i);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(indexes);
```

It can be done also using `filter` as follows :

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Apple"];
var keys = [];
var filtered = fruits.filter((e, i) => {
  if (e === "Apple") {
    keys.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(keys);
```